# How to install Nokia PC Suite on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, nokia

Where can I download and install the Nokia PC Suite for Ubuntu to tranfer data. I am not able to connect my Nokia C5 to my PC which has Ubuntu as OS without the help of Nokia PC Suite.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nokuntu/  watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjL7N5SDJ6c

Answer (score 1):

Nokia PC Suite isn't available for Ubuntu of any other Linux Distro. If having network problem then You can try `Nokuntu`.